# Four parties are competing in the elections, recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

this problem that I have difficulties to solve:

This question should be solved with a recurrence relation

**1.** The number $n$ is a non-negative integer.

**2.** Four parties are competing in the elections.

**3.** The number of mandates of all the parties together is $n$.

**4.** Party can get either 0 mandate, or minimum of 4.

Let $a_{n}$ be the number of ways to distribute the $n$ mandates between the 4 parties, so party get 0 or minimum of 4 mandates. The sum of the mandates should be $n$

My solution is:

I estimate that $n$ is at least 4, because nothing else is mentioned.
But maybe I'm wrong

I will divide into several cases:

**Case 1**: No new party will pass the percentage of blocking: $a_{n-1}$ options

**Case 2**: One new party will pass the percentage of blocking: But I'm not sure how to calculate that.

I would be very happy to receive your help.

Examples:
Those are the possible combinations:
for $n=8$ the only combinations are (0,0,4,4), (4,4,0,0), (4,0,4,0), (0,4,0,4).
for $n=9$ the only combinations are (0,0,4,5), (0,0,5,4),(4,5,0,0), (5,4,0,0),(4,0,4,0),(5,0,4,0), (0,5,0,4), (0,4,0,5)

Comment: The rules are a bit obscure, "percentage of blocking" has no obvious meaning.  I think you are just asking "how many ways are there to distribute $n$ distinguishable objects to $4$ distinguishable people", to which the answer is clearly $4^n$.  If that is wrong (likely enough) then please edit your post for clarity.  Working out $a_n$ explicitly for small $n$ might add clarity.

Comment: @lulu, The of the percentage of blocking is getting less than 4 mandates. So the combinations where there are parties that getting less than 4 mandates are not exists.

Comment: So...you are saying that each party must get at least $4$ mandates?  Or are you saying that either a party gets $0$ or at least $4$?  Something else?  Really, you need to edit your post for clarity.  Work out $a_n$ clearly and explicitly for small $n$.  If possible:  rephrase purely as a combinatorial question, with no reference to mandates or blocking or votes.  You are distributing distinct objects according to some rules, what are those rules?

Comment: @lulu I'm sorry, I have added examples, and edited the question.

Comment: So... Specify the subset that will get sooner mandates. Give each member $4$ to start, and the rest arbitrarily. Note: I was assuming that the mandates were distinct but your examples suggest that they are not.

Comment: Also, why can't one party get all 8 mandates?